# Properly set of .gitignore file in folder

Tags: git, visual-studio, github

I have a Repository on git with 2 folders.

[image]

One is ASP .NET Core Webapi, second is an React app. In main folder, i set `.gitignore` file genereted by `Visual Studio 2017` by `Git Settings` but it dont work properly.

When i add migration into my database, i get a lot of not necesery changes:

[image: enter code here]

My question is, where add `gitignore` file to make it work properly? Or how to set it for working with Visual Studio, React and .NET Core in same way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, git can only ignore untracked files.

> where add gitignore file to make it work properly?

You can have different locations for such file(s), under your home directory (i.e. `$HOME/.config/git/ignore`), `$GIT_DIR/info/exclude`, `$GIT_DIR/.gitignore` and `$GIT_DIR/**/.gitignore` (see `git help ignore` what is supported in your version of git).

Adding a pattern to the ignore file under your home directory will apply to all local git repositories.

`$GIT_DIR/info/exclude` only applies to the local repo, cannot be shared with your teammates.

`$GIT_DIR/.gitignore` and `$GIT_DIR/**/.gitignore` can be tracked by git and can be shared with your teammates.

A pattern like `*.txt` will exclude any txt-file in the same directory and any subdirectories as `.gitignore`.
A pattern like `/*.txt` will exclude any txt-file in the same directory as `.gitignore`.

A pattern like `!a*.txt` will include files matching this expression (even if it may have been excluded by some other ignore file).

You can use `git check-ignore -v <pathname>` to check what ignore expression is including/excluding a file or directory.